# Shadow is different depending on the camera position

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, hdri

I have this strange behavior on my project. With my camera setup, the shadow on the ground look strangly flat.
[image]

But if I move the same camera to a different place, it's ok.
[image]

I've checked normals direction, I've even try to modify the mesh but with no more luke.
[image]

I'm using a HDRi for lightning with Cycles.

Does someone have a clue?

[Blend file](https:////onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=1EB92D6BBECA3BC9&resid=1EB92D6BBECA3BC9%21497&authkey=ALPKrp3RrwSf4e0%22%20width=%2298%22%20height=%22120%22%20frameborder=%220%22%20scrolling=%22no%22)

Comment: please provide blend file...so we can check it out

Comment: I've added the blend file so you can check. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is optical illusion ... you just matched light direction parallel with object edge direction in Camera view ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems you're right!
I tested different lights and the problem disappeared.
Thanks a lot